# arp result interpretation

Tags: windows, arp

So what does the command `arp -a` do? I've been told it displayed the MAC addresses of all network cards on the computer, but when I ran it, it displayed three MACs for three IPs (192.168.41.1, .6, and .8 (24-bit subnet mask)). I assume the first is the router, but what could the other two be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those would be peer machines in your network that have made contact.